# Cannot include/exclude Junit tests classes by Category using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, junit, build.gradle, junit4

Given these interfaces

```
testclient.priority.High
testclient.priority.Low
```

and a junit classes annotated like this

```
@Category(testclient.priority.High.class)
public class MyTest {
...
}
@Category(testclient.priority.Low.class)
public class MyOtherTest {
...
}
```

I tried to configure an include/exclude pattern in build.gradle like this

```
useJUnit {
    includeCategories 'testclient.priority.High'
    excludeCategories 'testclient.priority.Low'
}
```

The problem is that **no tests** are run, at all. How is the exact syntax to achieve that?
I am using gradle 2.14.1 and invoke the tests by "clean build".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem myself. I missed the fact that

```
High extends Low
```

so the exclusion correctly affected all annotated tests. The extension is intended and the correct pattern in build.gradle would simply be:

```
useJUnit {
    includeCategories 'testclient.priority.High'
}
```

In fact there are five priority levels and the extension dependency is an easy way to configure something like "run everything of this level or higher".

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with Gradle 2.12. I don't know what is different between our respective environments, but I have placed [my solution on GitHub](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_JUnit_Category) for reference.

Note that I have placed `FastTest.java` and `SlowTest.java` in the `src/test/java/net/codetojoy` folder, where the tests reside.

Comment: Thank you. I checked everything and my settings (dependencies, repositories, apply plugin) are the same as in your example. The only difference I can see is the gradle version.