# progressively test my application by prioritizing test functions?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, webdriver

I have been using Java and Selenium along with JUNIT in order to create test cases.  I have been testing different parts of the application progressively.

IE:  Page navigation, then  Page Navigate and click on a particular button.

In that case, I have 2 test functions:

```
@Test
public void pageNavigation(){...}

@Test
public void buttonClickOnPage(){
  pageNavigation();

  WebElement ele = ....;
}
```

These don't necessarily run in the same order, so it might run `buttonClickonPage` first.  I was hoping to set up a priority queue in order to do something like a breadth first test of the application, testing all simple cases, then moving the more extensive cases.

I know these cases function independently which is fine, but 1 case might need the use of the another case, and build off of it.

Is there a way to do this within the Java Selenium and Junit scope.

*Thanks*

Comment: You might consider using Geb and Spock (basically DSLs on top of Selenium and JUnit), which roll up most of this functionality and make it easy to compose in the way you're asking about.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Test-execution-order... Use the @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING) at class level.

Answer (score 0):

I have prioritised my test classes using annotations extending hiearchically.

```
public interface High extends Medium
public interface Medium extends Low
public interface Low
```

The test class is annotated using another [Junit annotation](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/categories/Category.html) `org.junit.experimental.categories.Category` like this

```
@Category(testclient.priority.Medium.class)
public class MyMediumTest {
...
}
```

You include/exclude categories easily with maven or gradle. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872369/cannot-include-exclude-junit-tests-classes-by-category-using-gradle). It probably works on method level, as well.

Comment: Ill give this a shot to see if that works, because that would be a very awesome simple way to do it.  I was hoping to just do something like `@Test(Priority:1)` but this may do the trick just as well.  I was hoping to have more buckets, but I could extend your interfact structure to have more than 3 objects.